# Add information to textarea and save it in an array

Tags: php, html, css, textarea

Is it possible to do this in PHP + CSS? Got a textarea with the result of an array inside it:

```
<textarea class="ta_scripts"><?php
  foreach ($script as $script_launcher){
       echo $script_launcher."\r\n";
  }?></textarea><br><br>
```

The code below shows a textarea with something like this:

```
This is a beautiful line 1 from the array
This is a beautiful line 2 from the array
This is a more beautiful line 3 from the array
```

And so on.

So what I want is to add some text inside the textarea, then when click a submit button this text will be added to the array $scriptlauncher[]

If I wrote "this is my new text" then the result of textarea must be:

```
This is a beautiful line 1 from the array
This is a beautiful line 2 from the array
This is a more beautiful line 3 from the array
this is my new text
```

**My first approach:**
HTML and PHP and call to Javascript

```
<form name="frmscript" onsubmit="return false;">

        <?php if (isset($_POST["script"])) {

            $script = $_POST["script"];

          }?>

        <textarea class="ta_scripts" name="ta_scripts"><?php

                          foreach ($script as $script_launcher){
                              echo $script_launcher."\r\n";
                          }?>
        </textarea><br><br>

<input type="button" name="execscript" value="Execute scripts" id="submit" onClick="addtext();" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function addtext() {
    var newtext = document.frmscript.ta_scripts.value;
    document.frmscript.ta_scripts.value = "";
    document.frmscript.ta_scripts.value += newtext;
    window.location.href = "index.php?script=" + newtext; 
}
```

**Second Approach (can't save the new array yet)**
HTML and PHP and call to Javascript:

```
<form name="frmscript" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <?php /*if (isset($_POST["script"])) {*/
                    if($_POST){

                    $script = json_decode($_POST["script"]);

                    }

                    ?>

                    <textarea class="ta_scripts" name="ta_scripts"><?php

                          foreach ($script as $script_launcher){
                              echo $script_launcher."\r\n";
                          }?></textarea><br><br>

                  <input type="button" name="execscript" value="Execute scripts" id="submit" onClick="addtext();" />
                    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function addtext() {
  var script = document.frmscript.ta_scripts.value;
  document.frmscript.ta_scripts.value = "";
  document.frmscript.ta_scripts.value += script;
  script = JSON.encode(script);



  var miAjax = new Request({
      url: "index4.php",
      data: "script=" + script,
      onSuccess: function(textResponse){
      $('result').set("html", textResponse);
  },
  onFailure: function(){
    $('result').set("html", "Error!!");
}
})
  miAjax.send();
```

**Third approach (Any help would be much appreciated!):**

HTML and PHP:

```
<form name="frmscript" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <?php /*if (isset($_POST["script"])) {*/
                    if(isset($_GET['script'])){

                    $script = $_GET['script'];

                    }

                    ?>

                    <textarea class="ta_scripts" name="ta_scripts"><?php

                          foreach ($script as $script_launcher){
                              echo $script_launcher."\r\n";
                          }?></textarea><br><br>

                  <input type="button" name="execscript" value="Exec script" id="submit" onClick="addtext();" />
                    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('#execscript').click(function () {
/*        var name_val = $('input[name="script"]').val();*/
var script = document.frmscript.ta_scripts.value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "index4.php", //get response from this file
        data: {
            name: script
        },
        success: function (response) {

            $("textarea#ta_scripts").val(response); //send response to textarea
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So, when the textarea is changed you want the PHP variable `$scriptlauncher` to be updated?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, you get it!

Comment: PHP runs on a *server*. HTML runs on the *client* (the browser). You have to move the new content from the client to the server. This is usually done using AJAX and JSON.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen thank you, I'm trying with AJAX and It's working but can't send the variable from AJAX to PHP array. I think this part could be done with Json :)

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand you, but in order to read lines into an array:

```
$text = trim($_POST['testtextarea']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind

foreach ($textAr as $line) {
   //Push to scriptlauncher array.
    array_push($scriptlauncher, $line);

}
```

I've not tested this, but it should put you on the right track.

Comment: Well, I need to do it without reload the page. So this has become more complicated. : \

Comment: This is what AJAX is there for, you can POST data without the need of reloading. jQuery makes this much easier for us. I'll edit my answer to help you. Edit: Sorry I can't give you an AJAX example, there are plenty throughout StackOverlow. (I'm at work at the minute, oops!)